# How to fetch records in parallel for multiple conditions in cronjobs

Tags: php

I have a music library app containing many artists. I want to fetch records for multiple artists in parallel using multiple cronjobs. I am trying using the following code:

```
$track_q = $this->DbTracks->find()->where(["enrich_status"=>'pending'])->limit(250);
$tracks = $track_q->all();
/*** using that artists ***/
foreach($tracks as $track){
    $artist_q=$this->DbArtists->find()->where(["id"=>$track->artist_id]);
    $artist=$artist_q->first();
}
```

But it only fetches one artist at a time. I want to fetch multiple artists in parallel cronjobs doing something like this:

For cronjob one:

```
$track_q = $this->DbTracks->find()->where(["enrich_status"=>'pending', 'artist_id IN'=>[1,2,3,4,5]])->limit(250);
$tracks = $track_q->all();
//$track->artist_id; die;
foreach($tracks as $track){
$artist_q=$this->DbArtists->find()->where(["id"=>$track->artist_id]);
$artist=$artist_q->first();
```

For cronjob two:

```
/*** get records for artists having id 1,2,3,4,5 ***/
$track_q = $this->DbTracks->find()->where(["enrich_status"=>'pending', 'artist_id IN'=>[6,7,8,9,10]])->limit(250);
$tracks = $track_q->all();
/*** using that artists ***/
foreach($tracks as $track){
    $artist_q=$this->DbArtists->find()->where(["id"=>$track->artist_id]);
    $artist=$artist_q->first();
}
```

The problem is there are 1000s of artists so how can I manage them batched like above without specifying hard-coded ids?

Comment: Improve syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the modulo `%` operator on the `artist_id` column.

Assuming that you're using Laravel's Eloquent query builder, something like the following should work:

```
->whereRaw('artist_id % 2 = 0')->limit(250);  // All even artist_ids
```

… and in the second cron job:

```
->whereRaw('artist_id % 2 = 1')->limit(250);  // All odd artist_ids
```

---

**A note on the modulo operator:**

`x % 2` represents the remainder of *x divided by 2*. Thus, when *x % 2 = 0*, x must be an even number. Likewise, when *x % 2 = 1*, x must be an odd number.

You can extend the same example to an arbitrary number of subsets. When you want to assign *n* separate sets, just use *artist_id % n == x* where *x* can be any integer between 0 and *n-1*.

---

**Edit:**

The above only works as long as `artist_id` is numeric, of course.

---

### General Note:

I don't know what exactly your cron job is about to do with all the artist, but here's possibly another approach: Use the cronjob to query only the ids of all artists and then dispatch a separate job for each artist onto a job queue. Assign the job queue as many workers as you like and as your hardware can stand.